# Ionic 4 Google Login method returns error 12500

Tags: android, ionic4, google-signin

I am implementing a google plus login in android with Ionic 4. Following this tutorial https://ionicthemes.com/tutorials/about/ionic-google-login

Trying to login like this:

```
this.googlePlus.login({
            'scopes': 'profile email', 
            'webClientId': 'XXX ID From Web not Android Client ID XXX', 
            'offline': true 
        })
```

After making `ionic cordova run android` an running the app on my phone I get the error code `12500`

I read that it might have somthing to do with the SHA-1 key on my apk, but I have it registered on Firebase, so it can't be that.

I even checked for the apk for the SHA-1 and it is the same that I have registered on Firebase.

I'm pretty lost here on what it might be.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just solved the problem.

Apparently you have to complete the OAuth Consent Screen on the Google API and Services console.

After completing with a logo for the app and an email, the button for verification on the bottom of the console screen got enabled.

After that I just saved the OAuth consent screen and tried again on the App and it worked!